# Problem with UTL_SMTP package (sending emails from ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, email, ora-06512

Everything's been working fine and haven't made any changes to our mail packages. But i just noticed that our unsent_emails table has been filling up, and when i tried to manually sent the unsent emails (a periodic job set up in user_jobs) i get the following errors;

Error with main mail package: ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 501 5.5.2 MAIL FROM syntax error ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 20
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 98
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 221
ORA-06512: at "TRS.MAILPKG", line 63

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: The messages indicate that the format of the FROM line is not correct.  Can you post examples of some of the messages, particularly the FROM line?

Comment: the from line is mostly a single email address in this form; "email_address; " (with a white space after the ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was because of my "from" email (looked into it thanks to Bob Jarvis).. it didn't look like an email address (which have worked before but i think there were some changes to the email server which makes it not work now)

Answer (score 1):

Are all the unsent emails going out to multiple recipients ?

Here's a link to orafaq that suggests that it might have something to do with sending emails to multiple recipients and using the semicolon - ';' instead of the comma - ',' delimiter.

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/119863/2/

If this is the case, then try using a comma as a delimiter for multiple recipients

Comment: yeah i converted all the ';'s to ','s but it still didn't work.. thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with package '**utl_mail**':
it sends '**MAIL FROM:lzsiga@someserver.hu**'
but it should be '**MAIL FROM:<lzsiga@someserver.hu>**'

Whatever I specify as sender, it doesn't change this; on the other hand, RCPT TO is always correctly angle-bracketed, whatever I specify.

With '**utl_smtp**' it is enough to add angle brackets around the parameters of UTL_SMTP.MAIL and UTL_SMTP.RCPT.

Oracle does have examples which might help implementing utl_mail.send-like functions with utl_stml, so I'd suggest using that.